# Load selected record to modal window

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, mvvm, extjs6

I have a `grid` with `data`.
When I select a `row` and hit the 'edit' `button` on the `tbar`, I want to view a `window` (including a `form`) with the data from the `selected row`.
Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ukp

But I don't know how to access the current `selected row` or how to pass `data` from one `controller` to another (`GridController` --> `WindowController`).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the record to the window view.
In Extjs 6 you can use the `viewModel` and `bind` the fields, for example:

```
// In The controller

var selectionModel = grid.getSelectionModel();

Ext.create({
    xtype: 'my-window',
    viewModel: {
        data: {
            rec: selectionModel.getSelection()[0]
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
// The window 

items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Firstname',
    bind: '{rec.firstName}'
}, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Lastname',
    bind: '{rec.lastName}'
}]
```

Working example based on your code: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ukr

Comment: Wow this is great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Although this question is answered, I think it could be done differently (and cleaner) in two ways.

First the way CD uses, which is a great anwser, but much cleaner and without any logic in your `controller`. Just let the `viewmodel` do his job:

Config a `bind` property to the `selection` on your `grid`:

```
bind: {
    selection: '{rec}'
},
```

The fields stay the same:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Firstname',
    bind: '{rec.firstName}'
}, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Lastname',
    bind: '{rec.lastName}'
}]
```

That's it. Now you can remove the logic in your window `controller`.

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ulf

The second way, I use this a lot, is `deep binding` on your `viewmodel`. This is to keep track on the `record` that was selected, whatever or wherever it has changed. This can be accomplished by `bind` with `deep: true`.

In your (separate) `viewmodel` place a `formula`:

```
formulas: {
    rec: {
        // We need to bind deep to be notified on each model change
        bind: {
            bindTo: '{myGrid.selection}', //--> reference configurated on the grid view (reference: myGrid)
            deep: true
        },
        get: function(record) {
            return record;
        },
        set: function(record) {
            if(!record.isModel) {
                record = this.get('records').getById(record);
            }
            this.set('currentRecord', record);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! this really looks better.. :-)

Comment: bind selection does NOT work for me. @CD 's answer does work! I am on ExtJS 6.5.1